# Jenkins: Mailer plugin authentication error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Morning all,

I have jenkins and I am using gmail acc to send notifications. It worked up until about 2 weeks ago.

In the pipeline I use:

```
step([$class: 'Mailer',
  notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
  recipients: "someone@xx.com",
  sendToIndividuals: true
])
```

Jenkins is set up correctly, both e-mail notifications and extended e-mail notifications are configured the same way. Allow less secure apps in gmail settings is on.

When I send test email, it works. When I use it from pipeline or freestyle job, it fails:

```
ERROR: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 26sm2297642wmf.20 - gsmtp

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 26sm2297642wmf.20 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:130)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:175)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:138)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

I did follow all of the google suggested troubleshooting steps except for the App Password as I can't exactly use it with the email address I am using. Can anyone point me at the right direction on how to solve this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the mailer plugin from 1.27 to 1.23, which was suggested to solve different issue (exact opposite, where test mail wouldn't go through but it would work in jobs) and it solved the issue.